# Redirect output to console

Tags: c#, console, io-redirection

Fairly simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer.

What's the C# equivalent to doing `echo "foo" > CON` in a Windows batch script?

Note that I have to *specifically* output to the console stream (`CON`). I've found lots of answers addressing how to redirect it when calling `Process.Start()`, but my process is launched and `STDOUT` is redirected outside of my control.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682075(v=vs.85).aspx might help, with `Console.SetOut()` and some P/Invoke.

Comment: [AttachConole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: I'm just boggled that this is so hard for me to find an answer to.  It's *trivial* in a shell script, so it feels like it should be almost as easy in a stronger language...  A P/Invoke could probably do it, but that feels like trying to use a sledgehammer on a tiny nail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Console.OpenStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16f09842.aspx) to open the standard output stream, wrap that in a TextWriter and then use Console.SetOut to reset it.

Comment: Doesn't that just get the existing `STDOUT`?

Comment: @Bobson The documentation says it permits to reacquire the standard output stream.  I'm not sure whether this will allow you to "undo" a redirect that's occurring outside of your application.  That standard output redirect may simply be entirely out of your control (at least without P/Invoking some Win32 function, but I'm not very familiar with that).

Comment: Just tried it.  Didn't get any output.  Thanks for giving it a shot, though.

Answer (score -1):

The [`WriteConsoleOutput()` API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will do this.